# Earliest TV show/movie to have an actor portray a comic book character with dissimilar ethnicity?

Tags: movie, comics, tv, history-of

With the new [*Fantastic Four*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cwh48VDMZxg) (yet another Hollywood reboot) coming out soon, it's great to see that the actor [Michael Jordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_B._Jordan) (nah... not that one) playing the Human Torch isn't another white actor portraying an original white character. I like how a number of directors employ actors not based on appearance or comparing them to an original character that they are playing.

So my question is: **what is the earliest TV show/movie which featured an actor whose ethnicity did not match that of the original character in the comic?**

Comment: Do Turkish Batman or Japanese Spider-Man count?

Comment: Does a Welsh Reed Richards count (okay, probably not the earliest example) ?

Comment: +1. I wonder if the earliest such cases might actually be whitewashes, though, rather than the reverse? Or, worse yet: white actors in blackface. So if you're specifically looking for the earliest *non*-soul-crushing example, you might want to specify . . .

Comment: I couldn't stomach the racism in the Batman serial films from the 40s, but I'd be shocked if there weren't some Caucasian actors in yellow face playing up Japanese racial stereotypes there. I imagine that at least a handful of those appeared concurrently in the comics.

Comment: @Politank-Z - Haha love the trailers for those! I probably should have mentioned in the question but I meant TV shows or movies which stay true to the setting of the original character (e.g. Gotham is the main setting for Batman, don't think this is the same for Turkish Batman but I wouldn't be suprised if it was based in [Batman, Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman,_Turkey)).

Comment: @EikePierstorff - In this case, not as both Reed Richards and [Hornblower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioan_Gruffudd) are both white and I was looking for a more significant difference (i.e. race, colour etc) :)

Comment: [Ming the Merciless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_the_Merciless#Yellow_peril)  from Flash Gordon was played by a white American in the movie serials. Ming was depicted as A Fu Manchu type Asian, but he was technically an alien.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the first major race-swap was [Eartha Kitt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eartha_Kitt) as [Catwoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catwoman) in 1963 for the third season of the live-action Batman series.

Catwoman had originally been designed in 1940 (*Batman* #1) as a white woman.

[image: Original design]

Previous to Kitt, the role had already been played by two white actresses ([Julie Newmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julie_Newmar) and [Lee Meriwether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Meriwether)). Kitt's portrayal was the first time Catwoman had been depicted to be a woman of color or of any other race (though, an argument could possibly made for Meriwether's Russian portrayal in the live-action movie). Of course, Catwoman's race would later be swapped again in the [2004 *Catwoman* film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catwoman_%28film%29), when she was played by [Halle Berry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halle_Berry).

[image: Kitt as Catwoman]

Comment: +1, fantastic answer! It's been a while since I last saw the Batman series with Adam West :). Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It was 1967 not 1963.

Answer (score 1):

Does it count if the actor is pretending to be the character's race?

There was a Charlie Chan comic strip in 1938, but in film the character was routinely played by a Caucasian actor.